# Early stopping in wilcoxon signed rank test?

Tags: optimization, wilcoxon-signed-rank, sequential-analysis, optimal-stopping

I have decided to acquire N joint samples of variables X and Y (for example, N=200), and test whether their means are different using the [signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). I will repeat this procedure many times, each time for a different pair of variables. In my application, acquiring samples is a very expensive procedure, so I would like to acquire as few samples as possible on average per procedure. I would like to try the following trick: acquire 1 sample at a time, and make a check after every sample on whether it is still realistic that the null-hypothesis will be rejected. If I am already convinced that I will not be able to reject the null hypothesis after e.g. 10 samples, then there is no need to repeat the procedure for the rest of them.

I would like to further illustrate what I mean by early stopping using binomial distribution as an example. Let's say I want to check if a certain coin is more likely to flip heads than tails with p-value of 0.01 or better using N=200 samples. If my first 3 measurements are tails, then, even if all other 197 measurements end up heads, the p-value will be 3/200 = 0.015, so I will fail to reject the null hypothesis regardless of what the remaining 197 measurement results are, so I might as well stop after just 3 measurements

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis

Comment: Thanks for the link. While it is good to know the keyword, I must admit that the article is quite brief. Could you recommend a method that is currently considered standard practice for this problem?

Comment: I am sorry for being too brief. I am not an expert on this topic either so I can't give you better answer, the only thing i know is that if you do it as you proposed, you will get overly optimistic p-values.

Comment: No worries, I'll use the keyword to search :) Thanks for your help